# accept username , password from user and pass them as parameters to selenium web driver Junit test case

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

```
<form action="GetFormData.jsp" method="post">
    Username:<input type="text" name="txtUsername"><br><br>
    Password:<input type="password" name="txtPassword"><br><br>
</form>
```

Accept user credentials from user using this form and pass these values of username & password to a Junit test case.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)   
public class SeleniumTestcaseParameterized {

WebDriver driver;
private String userName,password;
public SeleniumTestcaseParameterized(String userName,String password)
{
    this.userName=userName;
    this.password=password;
}

@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data(){

    Object[][] data= new Object[][]{{"usernameFromForm","passwordFromForm"}};
    return Arrays.asList(data);
}
 ........
}
```

How to get these form values at runtime and pass as parameters?